# making json data a clickable link in html

Tags: html, json, hyperlink, styles

I have json data which is displayed on an html page javascript, I was wondering if there was a way to make this information clickable like a link. Anyone know how this would be done?

Here is my json, I want to pick up each name from the json file and make it clickable.

```html
{
    "example": [
        {
          "name": "Dr. Sammie Boyer",
          "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Eladio Beier",
          "email": "Lavonne.Kiehn@hotmail.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Hilton Borer",
          "email": "Reva.Goyette@yahoo.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code I tried

```html
$(document).ready(function() {


    $.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
         var output = '';
         $.each(data.name, function(key, value) {
                output += '<a href=' + value.name + '</a>';
        });
       
        $('#user').html(output);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you have any examples you can give us? What have you tried? Do you want the entire JSON clickable or only specific parts?

Comment: Can you add an example of the json data you want clickable

Comment: json has been added

Comment: @Rebkah Do you want to  display as it is or loop through it and display each name in a list then make each item on that list clickable?

Comment: guess it would have to be in a loop so that each name is in a list and each item is clickable

Comment: I originally had the names simply display in a list but they weren't clickable

Comment: Ok can you post the code you for making the names clickable

Comment: just added it to my question

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (updated) - Set the value of the `href` as you loop

```
$.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
      var output = '';
      $.each(data.name, function(key, value) {
            output += '<a href="emailto:' + value.email + '">'  + value.name + '</a>';
    });

    $('#user').html(output);
});
```

Comment: was able to get it working myself, just need to work out how when each name is clicked that the link does something

Comment: @Rebekah I updated the answer. Set the value of the href as you loop

Comment: thank you, I actually wanting to link to a hidden div but after seeing this I think I have an idea how it might be done

Comment: A hidden div? Ok maybe next time be a little more descriptive, don't live anything out.

Comment: how do I give each link a class or id?

Comment: `<a href="emailto:' + value.email + '" class="class_' + key+ '">'  + value.name + '</a>';`

Comment: and maybe you should accept the answer since I answered your original question about setting links

Answer (score 0):

just replace emailto with mailto to be like this

```
$.getJSON('example.json', function(data) {
      var output = '';
      $.each(data.name, function(key, value) {
            output += '<a href="mailto:' + value.email + '">'  + value.name + '</a>';
    });

    $('#user').html(output);
});
```